# Does $(L_{p+1}+2)\equiv0 \mod p$ only when $p^2$ have digits in nondecreasing order?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, fibonacci-numbers, lucas-numbers

Let $L_n$ be the $n$th Lucas number and $p$ a prime number.

I noticed something with Lucas Number : it seems than $(L_{n+1}+2)\equiv0 \mod n$ is right only when $n$ is a prime $p$ and only if $p^2$ has digits in nondecreasing order.

For example :

- $(L_{5+1}+2) = 18+2 = 20$ and $20\equiv0 \mod 5$ and $5^2 = 25$. $25$ has digits in nondecreasing order
- $(L_{7+1}+2) = 47+2 = 49$ and $49\equiv0 \mod 7$ and $7^2 = 49$. $49$ has digits in nondecreasing order
- $(L_{11+1}+2) = 322+2 = 324$ and $324\equiv5 \mod 11$ and $11^2 = 121$. $121$ has not digits in nondecreasing order
- $(L_{13+1}+2) = 843+2 = 845$ and $845\equiv0 \mod 13$ and $13^2 = 169$. $169$ has digits in nondecreasing order
- $(L_{17+1}+2) = 5778+2 = 5780$ and $5780\equiv0 \mod 17$ and $17^2 = 289$. $289$ has digits in nondecreasing order
- $(L_{19+1}+2) = 15127+2 = 15129$ and $15129\equiv5 \mod 19$ and $13^2 = 361$. $361$ has not digits in nondecreasing order
- $(L_{37+1}+2) = 87403803+2 = 87403805$ and $87403805\equiv0 \mod 37$ and $37^2 = 1369$. $1369$ has digits in nondecreasing order

I tested with the sequence https://oeis.org/A028865 and it works until 337 for me. (I didn't check higher)

Is there a way to explain that ? I don't know how to start for proving it.

Comment: It seems highly unlikely that there would be a condition like this on the digits, because the digits of a base $10$ representation is fairly arbitrary. It is quite possible that $n$ must be prime, however.

Comment: @tom not entirely. Certain digital patterns lend themselves to "sorted" squares, e.g. $17^2=289, 167^2=27889, 1667^2=2778889, ...$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The primes $p$ for which $L_{p+1}\equiv-2\bmod p$ end with $2, 3, 5$ or $7$. The primes in the OEIS sequence, whose squares must end with $4, 5,$ or $9$ for the digit ordering to work, meet this criterion, but there are also other primes for which $L_{p+1}\equiv-2\bmod p$. For instance, $p=23$ would satisfy the modular relation but $23^2=\color{blue}{52}9$.

The next unlisted primes ending in $3$ or $7$ are $43,47,53$ and these also appear to hold the modular relation, but their squares again do not have all digits sorted.

Comment: Aside from $p=5,$ these are the primes for which there is no $\sqrt 5$ modulo $p,$ which means the closed formula for the Lucas numbers involves $\sqrt 5,$ so this means we can’t look at the formula in the field $\mathbb F_p,$ but instead we must look in the field $\mathbb F_{p^2}.$

Comment: Still, $p =23$ holds. Rephrased to cut down 9n this issue.

Comment: Indeed you're right for 23 I didn't check this number